# Why does $\vec{B}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (B^2)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

$$\vec{B}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (B^2)$$

Griffiths states this result in his derivation of the Pontying vector, but I have absolutely no idea where it came from or how to go about deriving it myself. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is really a maths question, but it's true for any magnitude of a vector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just an application of the product rule.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(B^2)&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{B})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}\cdot\vec{B}+\vec{B}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} \right)\\
&=\vec{B}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

It is a result of the chain rule:

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial({f}^2)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}_\text{inner derivative} \ \ \ \ \underbrace{ \frac{\partial (f^2)}{\partial f}}_\text{outer derivative}   = f \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.$$

Apply this to all three components of $\vec{B}$, add, and you are done.